# Kitchen doesn't recognise docker

Tags: docker, chef-infra, test-kitchen

The problem is quite simple:

```
$ kitchen converge
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.6.0)
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::UserError
>>>>>> Message: You must first install the Docker CLI tool http://www.docker.io/gettingstarted/
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

In the log:

```
Message: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of sudo -E docker >> /dev/null 2>&1 ----
STDOUT:
STDERR:
---- End output of sudo -E docker >> /dev/null 2>&1 ----
Ran sudo -E docker >> /dev/null 2>&1 returned 1
```

Though `sudo -E docker >> /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?` says `0`.

- Kitchen `version 1.6.0`
- Docker `1.10.3, build 20f81dd` installed through `homebrew`

---

**EDIT**:

```
---
driver:
  name: docker 
  binary: docker #also tried with /usr/local/bin/docker
  privileged: true
```

Comment: Try configuring the full path to the right docker executable.

Comment: @coderanger I have edited my question ... but same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had helped outside and found the solution.

```
docker-machine env default
```

Was returning:

```
Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running
```

The solution was:

```
docker-machine start
```

And then, copy paste and run the output of:

```
docker-machine env default
```

Now:

```
kitchen converge
kitchen verify
```

work as expected.